# Подключение второй БД к проекту

Tags: mysql, база-данных, firebird

Добрый день!
Имеется сайт работающий на фреймворке Yii2 и базой данных MySQL. Мне нужно подключить дополнительно БД Firebird с которой нужно будет брать некоторые данные и выводить их в таблицу на сайт. Как и где мне сделать постоянное второе подключение ко второй БД?